# Mongo querying if array contains value

Tags: arrays, mongodb, subquery

I have such document tructure:
[image]

I need to find all documents where 'full' key is equal to '20200518_cbmoAXY.jpeg'

The best query I ended up with is:

```
db.getCollection('Advert').find({ $where: "this.images && this.images.length && (this.images[0].full == '20200518_cbmoAXY.jpeg')" })
```

But it finds nothing although record is present.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved:

```
 db.getCollection('Advert').find({ 'images.0.full' : '20200518_cbmoAXY.jpeg'})
```

Comment: If you only need one result `findOne` will return that result instead of a cursor.

Comment: I'm running this in shell for checking presense of records, would be much happier  to end up with query where specifying 0.full would be not required and scanning of all nested subvalues  would happen.  Not able to write such query yet. So so ok with this